# MySQL data provider / connector not available in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector, dataprovider

I tried everything, but cant make MySQL working in VS 2017. Apparently, there is support for VS2017 in the latest version of MySQL, but that does not work either.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-what-is-new-12.html

[image]
[image]

How do I enable MySQL in VS 2017 ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with MySql in VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

Support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 added since MySQL for Visual Studio version 1.2.7. Please **use [actual version of MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)!**

Answer (score 0):

Your link to MySQL refers to version 1.2, however version 2.0 is also available, check here: [MySQL 2.0 for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-what-is-new-20.html)

Have you installed the [ADO.Net driver from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to add support for MySQL connections to Visual Studio?